# How to see opened connections /running queries in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

How can I see opened connections /running queries in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the DMVs:

- [`sys.dm_exec_connections`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181509.aspx)
- [`sys.dm_exec_sessions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176013%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)
- [`sys.dm_exec_request`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)
- [`sys.dm_exec_sql_text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181929%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Additionally:

- from the [Activity Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175518.aspx)
- from [SQL Profiler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx)
- from [`sp_whoIsActive`](http://whoisactive.com)